# Using Polymer core elements in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer, dart-webui

Is there a way to use existing Polymer *standard* core elements , such as core-toolbar and core-menu, in Dart?

If you download the polymer project with bower you can find the javascript versions in `/polymer/bower-components/`.

core-toolbar, for instance, contains a `core-toolbar.html` and a `metadata.html`. These have `<polymer-element>` tags in them just like in Dart. Can these be adapted?

Comment: The PolymerDart team wrote a comment a few weeks that Polymer.js and PolymerDart should basically work together  on the same page and that they will continue to improve interoperability but I haven't tried it yet. You can also take a look at the Dart port https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_elements, https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_ui_elements. Core elements are mostly a selection of polymer_elements/polymer_ui_elements.
Not all of these elements are fully working yet though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this issues:

- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=14098
  This is not the post I talked about in my comment.
- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=13758
  The linked discussion in this issue could be the post I remembered
- the TodoMVC is a Dart demo project (https://www.dartlang.org/samples/) that uses some Polymer.js polymer_elements
  [see source in lib-elements directory](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/samples/third_party/todomvc/#todomvc/web/lib-elements)

As mentioned in my comment alternatively you could use the Dart port of polymer_elements and polymer_ui_elements

- https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_elements
- https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_ui_elements

Comment: From what you say I understand we're half way there with Eriks work, but not everything is available.

Comment: Actually since a few months development and maintenance is mostly done by me and it is work in progress. This is because polymer_elements/polymer_ui_elements/core_elements is a moving target (core elements exist only a few weeks as far as I know) and because I can't spend as much time as I would to working on this project and partially because PolymerDart lacks or lacked some features which blocked progress.

Comment: Well you really are a busy bee aren't you! Where do you find the time and the stamina. Does Google pay you to be on Dart watch all day?

Comment: Because Dart is fun :-) I would love that, but no, Google doesn't pay me. But I learn a lot myself by solving other peoples problems, so I think it pays off in some way.

Comment: Thanks for your generous spirit Günter! I might have more questions coming though, so beware ;)

Answer (score 5):

In the meantime, an official package has arrived:

http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/core_elements

And you can even have the paper elements of the material design:

http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/paper_elements

Comment: Thanks for the update. These packages are already available for about a month. They have several issues. It's important to use `Polymer 0.12-0-dev` release which contains several fixes. A new release of `core-elements` and `paper-elements` should be published soon which fixes a lot of issues.